# remove uninstalled bower package from list

Tags: git, bower

I am new to Bower/Grunt and made a mistake when adding a package to bower by using the GitHub page and not the .git file url.
I have erroneously installed the package using

```
bower install https://github.com/knsv/mermaid --save
```

To remedy I tried:

```
bower uninstall mermaid
```

however now I still see the package listed when I type 'bower list'
I am assuming that the --save option added the dependency to my bower.json file and my first thought is to simply remove the reference in this file.

Will modifying this file cause any unforeseen issues?

Comment: Actually I found another approach - I could re-install and the remove with the --save switch so no need to hack the json. But still curious whether it is normal/ok to hack the json file directly and whether there are any gotchas to look out for.